# C# How to set and get items from object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, datatable

I've been a VB.Net programmer for a long time ago but recently I started learning C#. I know Vb.Net shares many features C# has and viceversa, so I'm trying to "cast/parse" my class code files (the most I use) to C# native. But I've been facing a issue with objects, because it seems to me (maybe I'm wrong) that they're not structured the same as they're in Vb.Net

There are some properties of objects that might be missing or I can't find, and I don't know what are their C# equivalent. Right now I have these.

```vb
Private g as object
```

Now if a want to add/assing a new value to object I write

```vb
g.item("exampleKey") = "exampleValue"
```

But if I try this in C#

```cs
private object g;
g.item("exampleKey") = "exampleValue"
```

The last line gives me an error

In the other hand If I want to populate "g" object with a DataTable "s", that I previously used when filling TableAdapter "E"

```vb
E.fill(s)
```

I write

```vb
g = s.NewRow
```

or

```vb
g = s.Rows(0)
```

after all this I begin object edition by doing

```vb
g.BeginEdit()
```

Then I edit by doing the same as above, and after that I end edition by doing

```vb
g.item("exampleKey") = "exampleValue"
g.item("exampleKey2") = "exampleValue3"
...
g.endEdit()
```

And if I want to add "g" object as a Row for DataTable "s" I write

```vb
s.rows.add(g)
```

And Finally if I want to update TableAdapter "E" with DataTable "s" I make

```vb
E.update(s)
```

How do I write the same but in C#? I know there are IEnumerables, Lists, Dictionary, IDictionary.. etc but I don't know which is the closest approach I can use in my case.

Comment: If you know how to write it in vb.net, I'd say go ahead and write it that way, then run it through a code converter (there's numerous free code converters online for .net languages).  Usually what you feed them works out rather well, and even if it's not exact, it's usually close enough that you can tell what's going on at that point.

Answer (score 3):

Index and key-based selectors in C# use square brackets. For example:

```
g["exampleKey"] = "value"; // Equivalent to VB.NET --> g.Item("exampleKey") = "value";
```

Comment: Except that usually there is no visible 'Item' property available from C#, so you'd just use "g[index]".

Comment: Ahhh, good point. Wasn't aware that Item was used as the equivalent for index in VB.NET. Mistakenly assumed it was a custom collection property on the object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to correlate that all of your code, derive from an `object`.  So what you'll need to do is realize the structure for *C#*.  Important thing to note:

```
public class Example
{
     public Example()
     {
         // Constructor
     }

     public void Method()
     {
         // Call Method, which will perform a task.
     }

     public string Demo { get; set; } // Property
}
```

So in our `object`, `Example` you have a couple of items.  The *Constructor* which will be initialized at the time your `object` is constructed.  If you do not add one the CLR will automatically add one.  Your *Method* which will be constructs to perform task of your choosing.  Then a *Property*, which I have as an *anonymous property* at the moment.

To call this object you would simply do:

```
Example example = new Example();
example.Demo = @"Value";
```

You've assigned a value now to your *property*, you've also built an `object`.

Obviously this is a demonstration, it isn't the most useful but coupled with a *delegate* it is quite useful.  Hopefully this provides some insight, but in regards to your issue:

`Index` or a `Key` are implement with square brackets `[ ]`.  So you would need to do:

```
g.Item["ExampleKey"] = "value";
g.Item["ExampleKey"].Value = "value";
```

May vary based on what your attempting to do.  Hopefully this helps-

Comment: I do the same you recommend g.Item["ExampleKey"] = "value" and I get this error "Unknown member 'Item' of 'object'"
Ps: I also tried "item" (lowercase), but the error keeps showing

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)